# Node.js process.exit() does not exit cleanly, and the dangers of async fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

## **tl;dr:**

Calling the asynchronous `fs.writeFile` from asynchronous events (and perhaps even from just a plain old loop) and then calling `process.exit()` successfully opens the files but fails to flush the data into the files. The callbacks given to `writeFile` do not get a chance to run before the process exits. *Is this expected behavior?*

Regardless of whether `process.exit()` is failing to perform this cleanup, I call into question whether it should be node's duty to at least attempt to work the file writes into the schedule, because it may very well be the case that the deallocation of huge buffers depends on writing them out to disk.

## details

I have a conceptually basic piece of node.js code which performs a transformation on a large data file. This happens to be a LiDAR sensor's data file, which should not be relevant. It is simply a dataset that is quite large owing to the nature of its existence. It is structurally simple. The sensor sends its data over the network. My task for this script is to produce a separate file for each rotating scan. The details of this logic is irrelevant as well.

The basic idea is I use node_pcap to read a huge `.pcap` file using the method given to do this task by node_pcap, which is "offline mode".

What this means is that instead of asynchronously catching the network packets as they appear, what appears to be a rather dense stream of asynchronous events representing the packets are "generated".

So, the main structure of the program consists of a few global state variables, and a single callback to the pcap session. I initialize globals, then assign the callback function to the pcap session. This callback to the `packet` event does all the work.

Part of this work is writing out a large array of data files. Once in a while a packet will indicate some condition that means I should move on to writing into the next data file. I increment the data filename index, and call `fs.writeFile()` again to begin writing the new file. Since I am writing only, it seems natural to let node decide when a good time is to begin writing.

Basically, both `fs.writeFileSync` and `fs.writeFile` should end up calling the OS's `write()` system call on their respective files in an asynchronous fashion. This does not bother me because I am only writing, so the asynchronous nature of the write which can affect certain access patterns does not matter to me since I do not do any access. The only difference is in that `writeFileSync` forces the node event loop to block until such time as the `write()` syscall completes.

As the program progresses, when I use `writeFile` (the js-asynchronous version), hundreds of my output files are created, but no data is written to them. Not one. The very first data file is still open when the hundredth data file is created.

This is conceptually fine. The reason is that node is busy crunching new data, and is happily holding on to the increasing number of file descriptors that it will eventually get to in order to write the files' data in. Meanwhile it also has to keep inside of memory all the eventual contents of the files. This will eventually run out, but let's ignore the RAM size limitation for a moment. Obviously a bad thing to happen here would be running out of RAM and crashing the program. Hopefully node will be smart and realize it just needs to schedule some file writes and then it can free a bunch of buffers...

If I stick a statement in the middle of all this to call `process.exit()`, I would expect that node will *clean up and flush the pending `writeFile` writes* before exiting.

But node does not do this.

Changing to `writeFileSync` fixes the problem obviously. 
Changing and truncating my input data such that `process.exit()` is not explicitly called also results in the files eventually getting written (and the completion callback given to `writeFile` to run) at the very end when the input events are done pumping.

This seems to indicate for me that the cleanup is being improperly performed by `process.exit()`.

**Question:** Is there some alternative to exiting the event loop cleanly in the middle? Note I had to manually truncate my large input file, because terminating with `process.exit()` caused all the file writes to not complete.

This is node `v0.10.26` installed a while ago on OS X with Homebrew.

Continuing with my thought process, the behavior that I am seeing here calls into question the fundamental purpose of using `writeFile`. It's supposed to improve things to be able to flexibly write my file whenever node deems it fit. However, apparently if node's event loop is pumped hard enough, then it will basically "get behind" on its workload.

It is like the event loop has an inbox and an outbox. In this analogy, the outbox represents the temp variables containing the data I am writing to the files. The assumption that a lazy productive programmer like me wants to make is that the inbox and outbox are interfaces that I can use and that they are flexible and that the system will manage for me. However if I feed the inbox at too high a rate, then node actually can't keep up, and it will just start piling the data into the outbox without having any time to flush it because for one reason or another, the scheduling is such that all the incoming events have to get processed first. This in turn defers all garbage collection of the outbox's contents, and quite quickly we deplete the system's RAM. This is quite easily a hard-to-find bug when this pattern is used in a complex system. I am glad I took a modular approach to this project.

I mean, yes, clearly, obviously, beyond all doubt the answer is to use `writeFileSync` as I do almost every single time that I write files with node.

What, then, is the value in even *having* `writeFile`? At this point I am trading a potential small increase in parallel processing for the increased possibility that if (for some reason) the machine's processing capability drops (whether it's thermal throttling or OS level scheduling or I don't pay my IaaS bills on time, or any other reason), that it can potentially lead to a snowballing memory explosion?

Perhaps this is getting at the core of solving the truly rather complex problems inherent in streaming data processing systems, and that I cannot realistically expect this event-based processing model to step up and elegantly solve these problems automatically. Maybe I should be satisfied that it only gets me about half of the way to something robust. Maybe I am just projecting my wishes onto it and that it is unreasonable for me to assume that node needs to less deterministically "improve" the scheduling of its event loop.

Comment: `writeFile` can be very useful in most cases, even if it seems to be broken in this case.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder what it is that I want. Maybe it just needs to have a little warning in the documentation? I mean, it almost seems like the entire implementation of `writeFile` is just `setTimeout(function(){fs.writeFileSync(args.slice(-1))},0)`. I just don't really know where to go from here. On the one hand, the "faulty" behavior is easily explained. And the "proper" behavior can easily turn itself into incomprehensible magic.

Comment: Well, every high level language implements an intermediate step between calling `.write` and actual data appearing on the disk: the internal buffer. So the behaviour is expected imho. Have you tried using [.fsync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fsync_fd_callback) (yes, the documentation sucks, but google it)? It is designed to ensure that the data appears on the disk. If that doesn't work, then you can do a manual cleanup by registering a handler to `process.on('exit', clb)`.

Comment: The same does not happen when using `fs.open` then `fs.write`. I couldn't manage to create 0 size file. This is somehow strange inconsistency between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a node expert but it seems like your problem can be simplified using streams. Streams let you pause and resume and also provide other neat functionality. I suggest you take at look at Chapter 9 of Professional NodeJS by Pedro Teixeira. You can find an online copy easily for reading purposes. It provides very detailed and well explained examples on how to use streams to read and write data and also prevent potential memory leaks and loss of data.

Comment: While it's interesting to consider a new option, I find it hard to believe that streams could be any sort of improvement on the solution that is `writeFileSync`. If I were to use streams in any asynchronous way, I would still fall prey to the exact same problem of the event loop being pumped full.